# google-api Error exception Math_BigInteger

Tags: google-api-php-client

When using:

```
$client  = new \Google_Client(['client_id' => config('services.google.client_id')]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($request->idToken);
```

I got the error:

```
local.ERROR: ErrorException: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Math_BigInteger has a deprecated constructor in /vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php:176
```

I tried to update all libs but without success.